# Format of params structure expected by Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-web-api, strong-parameters

I'm working on an API-only Rails 5 app -- yes, I know. I haven't been around Rails for a while, so I was doing some long overdue catching up when I bumped into the good ol' nested hash of parameters, which I had completely forgotten about. Say I want to create a `User`, I thought I'd issue a POST request with the following parameters (let's make it JSON for simplicity):

```
{ "username": "myUsername", "password": "myPassword" }
```

However, after much grieving and googling, I discovered/remembered that I'm supposed to pass the following:

```
{ "user": { "username": "myUsername", "password": "myPassword" } }
```

which in turn makes the following

```
def user_params
  params.request(:user).permit(:username, :password)
end
```

happy.

All in all, I'm OK with that. This is going to be a private API for a mobile app, and I don't expect to open it up to anyone. However, I've been perusing other (typically restful-ish-like) APIs around the web, and none of them have the nested `model` business going on. I'll soon be working on a public API for a different project, so I was wondering if there is any particular reason for requiring that structure, and, if not, how can I maintain strong parameters without all the nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally convenient for `params[:user]` to refer to all the parameters for a user and without the risk of clashes with magic parameters such as controller, action, format and so on.

You can use [parameter wrapping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) to make this easy for API clients

If you add

```
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
```

To your controller then for JSON requests rails will wrap parameters that match user attributes in a hash (if your controller isn't called `UsersController` you'll need to tell action controller the class to use or the parameters that should be wrapped). This allows your controller code to stay unchanged but for API clients to post "bare" parameters.

You can also enable this globally for the whole application.

Comment: This means I can still use `user_params()` as it is and keep all the benefits of that, and strong parameters, right?